# Translating the dynamic data of a java application from english to multilanguages

Tags: java, jquery, hibernate, struts-1

I am trying to convert one java project into different languages(i.e, german) using struts(i18n). But i am unable to convert the dynamic data i.e, menus which are coming from database. With i18n concept i have changed the static content but not dynamic content.
Please give any solution to this problem.

Comment: How dynamic is your content, how are you handling translation now ? Be more clear/specific.

Comment: Our project contains menus and these menus will change for different users, so that's why we have saved the menus in database(mysql) using hibernates we are getting those with the respective column name and storing them in a VO then displaying in jsp.

Comment: Create menus  in multiple languages (in Db). give contry code as id. take Contry code from where client logins and fetch menu according to it.